# How do I fix "RPC method not found on object with PhotonView 1001"?

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon, photon-pun

I followed on stackOverFlow answers to make Playing audio to all players, but when i press fire button, it shows error.
Here the error :
`RPC method 'machineGunSound()' not found on object with PhotonView 1001. Implement as non-static. Apply [PunRPC]. Components on children are not found. Return type must be void or IEnumerator (if you enable RunRpcCoroutines). RPCs are a one-way message.`

And Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using TMPro;
using Photon.Pun.UtilityScripts;
using Photon.Realtime;
public class punSoundPlayer : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public AudioClip machineGun;

    public AudioSource audioSource;
    public void machine()
    {
        PhotonView photonView = GetComponentInParent<PhotonView>();
        photonView.RPC("machineGunSound", RpcTarget.All);
    }

    [PunRPC]
    public void machineGunSound()
    {
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(machineGun);
    }



    
}
```

i tried to check [PunRPC] but it looks doesn't have any problems

Comment: `PhotonView` must be on the *same* GameObject as your RPC method and component .. not on a parent. Btw afaik `MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks` also already has a reference to its own PhotonView in the inherited property [`photonView`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/current/class_photon_1_1_pun_1_1_mono_behaviour_pun.html#a87e5a9f9a07323813074b7358d5e85e3)